# Html преобразуется в текст

Tags: php, html

Кодом не вставляет, не могу понять. Как убрать это форматирование html на текст

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Куда не вставляет? Что не вставляет? Я вот ничего не понял что вам нужно.

Comment: Просто при отправке пост запроса в виде тегов, они преобразуются в простой текст, то есть теги преобразуются в символы

Answer (score 2):

Оберните ваш код в тег `<code>` или `<pre>`. Их отличия в том что `<pre>` учитывает дополнительные пробелы и переносы внутри контейнера, а в `<code>` нужно самостоятельно проставлять `<br>` или `<p>`.

upd

Используйте [обработку строк](http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.strings.php), например [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strip-tags.php) — удаляет HTML и PHP-теги из строки, [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars.php) — Преобразует специальные символы в HTML-сущности

Comment: Просто при отправке пост запроса в виде тегов, они преобразуются в простой текст, то есть теги преобразуются в символы. Тэги не помогают

Comment: добавила в ответ про обработку строк